# What is the probability that the sum is lower than 5?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

A normal six-sided die is rolled twice. It is known that the sum of the die is 9. What is the probability that the sum of the dice on the second roll is less than 5?

How I understood the question is that we have 4 ways to get sum of "9: 3 + 6, 4 + 5, 5 + 4, 6 + 3". But if we need to get the sum that's less than 5 after the second roll, we only have one option and that is to roll a 1 on the second roll, because with the remaining three, the sum is either equal to or more than 5.

What I mean is that, the first position after the first roll is occupied by one of the numbers which can give the sum of 9:

***3*** + 6; ***4*** + 5; ***5*** + 4; ***6*** + 3

and that is either a 3 or a 4, or a 5, or a 6. That is why on the second roll we can only roll a 1 if we want the sum to be less than 5.

Is this the correct way? And how would I need to write the solution?

Comment: How the first roll associates to the roll is not clear to me. For me, the first and the second roll are independent of each other and should be treated as such.

Comment: I am having difficulty reading your question and attempt because it seems you have frequently mixed up the numbers $1$ and $6$, have frequently mixed up the phrase "greater than" and "less than", and frequently misused the word "sum" in situations where we are not in fact summing anything.  I strongly suggest proofreading your post again.

Comment: If you meant to ask "*Given that the sum of two dice is 9, what is the probability the result of the second die is* **greater** *than 5*" and you meant to have in your analysis "*...4 ways to get the sum of 9: 3 &* **6**, *4 & 5, ...we need to get the* **value** *that's* **greater** *than 5 on the second roll, we have only one option and that is to roll a* **6** *on the second roll, because the remaining three are equal or* **less** *than 5*" then your answer and approach is correct, and shows the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Otherwise, if you do mean to have less, again, the same approach and analysis works, but there would be two "good" outcomes... namely 5&4 and 6&3, leading to a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.  All of this just screams that you need to pay more attention to which word is being used and to be consistent.

Answer (score -2):

The sum of the two die is 9 so if the first roll was 6 the second roll was must be 3< 5. The probability of that is 1/6.
If the roll on the first die was 5 the roll on the second die was 4< 5. The probability of that is 1/6.
Those are the only ways we can get less than 5 on the second roll and still get a total or 9.

The probability of this is 1/6+ 1/6= 1/3.

Comment: Completely wrong and does not address the issues the OP was having.  The probability of rolling a 3 on the second die may well be $\frac{1}{6}$ in ordinary circumstances, however here we know that the sum of the two dice is $9$.  The probability of rolling a 3 on the second die **given that** the sum of the two dice is $9$ will be something different.